# Stereo vision in Matlab

Tags: stereo-vision, matlab, soccer

I am working on a project about robot soccer vision.

How I utilize two webcams as a stereo vision in matlab for robot soccer matters?

Comment: The first google result seems useful http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/stereo-vision.html

Comment: Or take an online course: https://www.qut.edu.au/study/short-courses-and-professional-development/short-courses/robotic-vision

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question but here is how I would approach the problem:

1. Connect to each camera using the `videoinput` function.
2. Calibrate the cameras using a checkerboard pattern -- I am more familiar with using OpenCV to do this, but MATLAB has a `cameraCalibrator` function.
3. Analyze the stereo images to get a 3D interpretation of the scene. This is another broad field of study, but you can use `disparity` to try and create a complete depth image or pick out particular features using `detectSURFFeatures` (along with `extractFeatures`) and match them with `matchFeatures`.
4. Use the 3D data for high-level planning and control of the robot. This is tied back into how you analyze the images too, i.e., if you want to track particular objects like the ball or other robots, or estimate the relative pose of the opposing net, or generally localize the robot itself based on fiduciary markers or something.

The process of connecting to the cameras, calibrating, and extracting 3D data can be thought of as a work package in terms of getting your system working. However, the fourth item (using the data) is where you need to start so that you know what requirements and limitations to place on the algorithms.